# Why is this code not causing a race condition?

Tags: java, multithreading, race-condition

The below code increments a static variable within a Thread and checks to see if its value is incremented by one. This is what `Assert.assertEquals(currentAVal+1, accessCounter);` checks.

The test consistently passes for 10'000 runs. But why is no race condition causing the test to fail ?
I would expect two or more threads to increment `accessCounter` at line `accessCounter = accessCounter + 1;` before the assert takes place but this does not seem to be occurring ?

```
public class RunnableTest {
    private static int accessCounter = 0;

    private class Post implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            int currentAVal = accessCounter;
            accessCounter = accessCounter + 1;
            Assert.assertEquals(currentAVal+1, accessCounter);
            System.out.println("Access counter : "+accessCounter);
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void runTest(){
        Runnable r = new Post();    
        ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(4);
        for(int executorCount = 0; executorCount < 10000; ++executorCount) {  
            executor.execute(r);
        }
    }
}
```

Update : from Gray's answer I've updated the code and I am now receiving a race condition (test failure) when I remove the println statement :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.Test;

import junit.framework.Assert;

public class RunnableTest {

    private static int accessCounter = 0;
    private static List<String> li = new ArrayList<String>();

    private class Post implements Runnable {
        public synchronized void run() {

            int currentAVal = accessCounter;
            accessCounter = accessCounter + 1;
            li.add(String.valueOf(currentAVal+1+","+accessCounter));

        }
    }

    @Test
    public void runTest(){

        Runnable r = new Post();    
        ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(4);
        for(int executorCount = 0; executorCount < 10000; ++executorCount) {  
            executor.execute(r);
        }
        //Wait for threads to finish
        // we shut it down once we've submitted all jobs to it
        executor.shutdown();
        // now we wait for all of those jobs to finish
        try {
            executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for(String s : li){
            Assert.assertEquals(s.split(",")[0], s.split(",")[1]);
        }
    }

}
```

Adding `synchronized` to the run method causes the test to pass

Comment: Can you be sure that the actions are actually starting on different threads? The `ExecutorService` docs do not guarantee that your `Post`s will be run on different threads. Also, just because something *can* have a race condition doesn't mean it must show itself often.

Comment: `ExecutorService` certain _does_ guarantee that the `Posts` will run in different threads @frsfnrrg.  Maybe not in different processors but certainly in different threads.

Comment: @Gray Could you please cite the portion of the docs/source that shows it? I couldn't find anything in the java 7 documentation, other than that the `Executors` definition of a thread pool only limits the *maximum* number of threads in use. "At any point, at most nThreads threads will be active processing tasks." The `Executor` interface gives no information on threads; the `ExecutorService`, `ScheduledExecutorService`, and `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` say nothing about *how* the tasks are allocated to threads.

Comment: Well the first line of the `ExecutorService` javadocs mentions the word "asynchronous".  I'm also intimate with the implementations so although an `Executor` could run the job in the current thread, none of the concurrency classes do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The test consistently passes for 10'000 runs. But why is no race condition causing the test to fail ?

The definition of a race condition is that you *might* get timing problems -- it is not guaranteed.  If you ran this on another architecture you might get wildly different results.

However, I don't think that asserts in other threads are seen by junit.  For example, if I change you test the following.  I do see times that the value differs but the `fail` is not seen by the test method -- the test still passes.

```
if (currentAVal+1 != accessCounter) {
    System.out.println("Access counter not equal: "+accessCounter);
    Assert.fail();
}
```

One reason why you may be seeing proper values in `accessCounter` is that `System.out.println(...)` is a synchronized method which is (as a byproduct) synchronizing the value of `accessCounter`.

Also, you are not shutting down your executor nor are you waiting for the executor service to actually complete.  You should do something like:

```
// we shut it down once we've submitted all jobs to it
executor.shutdown();
// now we wait for all of those jobs to finish
executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

But this doesn't solve the other thread issue.  To actually see the results of the threads you could do something like:

```
List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<?>>();
for (int executorCount = 0; executorCount < 10000; ++executorCount) {
    futures.add(executor.submit(r));
}
executor.shutdown();
executor.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
for (Future<?> future : futures) {
    // this will throw an exception if an assert happened
    future.get();
}
```

Comment: why would the synchronization of the println method have an impact on the static variable since the rest of the code is un-synchronized ?

Comment: Crossing a memory barrier guarantees a happens-before relationship of _all_ previous memory operations.  When you call `println(...)` this ensures that the `accessCounter` updates from the current thread is stored to central storage.  It also guarantees that updates made by other threads are seen by the current thread.  It doesn't necessarily explain why you aren't seeing the race but it complicates matters @user470184.

Comment: maybe I am going off topic but what is a memory barrier ?

Comment: A memory barrier is what is crossed when you enter and exit a `synchronized` block.  There are both read and write versions and happen when you access `volatile` fields as well. http://www.infoq.com/articles/memory_barriers_jvm_concurrency

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the question itself. It's a race condition :
You can't guarantee that it will ever occur no matter HOW many times threads you try to throw at it or times you try to run it. That's why it's a race condition. It's `non-deterministic`

Assuming uniform probability distribution for this isn't even remotely correct unless you can show why.  You aren't flipping a coin here.  The code could run for months before the race is exposed, I've seen this very thing happen many times. That's why race conditions are hard to solve and important to prevent.

Secondly you aren't seeding any amount of random noise into the scenario. If you say had each thread's run function sleep a random amount of time first so that they actually were likely to coincide with one another this would be more intersting... but you're threads a so short they are likely finished and never even running in parallel compared to the time it takes to spawn dispatch the jobs.

Comment: Philosophically, you can never guarentee it, but when you make 10000 threads incrementing the same counter, there's something else going on. If the race was a 50-50, then the chance of this being by accident is 1 in 2^10000. As computer scientists I don't have to tell you how big this number is.

Comment: But your presumption that it is 50-50 is utterly absurd.  You presume that there is uniform distribution of probablity of the race coming out good or bad but this isn't true even remotely.  We aren't flipping a coin. This is thread scheduling by the JVM. 

Secondly, he fires them off linearly from a vector and the code path is small and identical every single time with VERY few instructions. Each thread could be completed before the next one is even started.... not like he injects any randomized sleeps or anything...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly as other answers have pointed out that Race is *not guaranteed* to occur. Remove the `sysout` statement as that can cause the code to synchronize.